# Does the "No True Scotsman" fallacy need the assertion to be changed?

Tags: fallacies

Or is it still a NTS fallacy if, instead of the original assertion being modified, it already contains provisions for rejecting falsifications as incorrectly run experiments?

If "**true** Scotsman" is in the assertion from the beginning, rather than added in response to a counterexample?


[edit: example given as demanded]

Situation 1:
Person 1: "No Cristian would rape a woman"
Person 2: Well, the news last evening...
Person 1: "He's not a *true* Christian"

Situation 2:
Person 1: "No true Cristian would rape a woman"
...

The question: If Situation 1 is a case of NTS, is Situation 2, also?

Without delving into definitions and unknowable thoughts of Person 1, the consensus here is be "no". Thank you.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking. Why don't you just give us the case you are worried about? that will be easier for people to help with.

Comment: Is the [argumentation] tag appropriate for this question? i.e. is it about actual arguments where  this might come up, or is this an *in principle* kind of question?

Comment: @shane No specific case. Any situation where a person utters "No Adjective Noun is X" while deliberately already thinking of the Adjective as meaning "the kind that isn't X" (obvious circular reasoning, now that I put it that way - so NTS is all in the modification)

Comment: yeah that seems obviously circular. Note that the following is a perfectly valid argument: (1) Every X is Y. (2) Z is not Y. (3) Therefore, Z is not X. "Every Scotsman loves porridge; Angus hates porridge; therefore Angus is not a Scotsman." The "No True Scotsman" fallacy is supposed to be committed when there's a kind of shifting, loose definition of the class of things that are X. It's an ad hoc way of trying to preserve some universal generalization against clear counterexamples.

Comment: @kaay your comment on the question here makes it sound like you'd like to withdraw the question since it's not about the nature of the "true scotsman fallacy". Elsewise, this seems to be either an "evolving question" or a "true scotsman question" in its own right. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @virmaior Not withdrawing, noticing that the answer becomes obvious once I rephrase the question.

Comment: The point of the no true scottsman fallacy is that you can't say that X would never do Y when X and Y are unrelated. If you qualify X to be more specific but in a way that's still unrelated, then your argument has not improved. If you say "X would never do something that by definition makes that one not-X," then you're just stating a tautology. I don't really see what the issue is behind the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the usual definition the assertion has to be modified ad hoc. One can imagine "pre-emptive" No True Scotsman with the original premise already designed to reject any objection to its conclusion. That however would be a case of circular reasoning/begging the question. Anselm's ontological argument can be read as  such a case: God that does not exist in reality is no true God. The trick is to put existence in reality into the definition of God under the guise of perfection.

Comment: I don't see how any fair reader could interpret Anselm's argument as a "no true scotsman" move. Maybe importing back some contemporary understandings of God we could get there, but given his understanding that makes no sense.

Comment: @virmaior Isn't "no fair reader" just No True Scotsman by another name? And it can be read that way because it was, here's Schopenhauer:"*On some occasion or other someone excogitates a conception, composed out of all sorts of predicates, among which, however, he takes care to include the predicate actuality or existence, either openly or wrapped up for decency's sake in some other predicate, such as perfection, immensity, or something of the kind*".

Comment: I'd rather say there's deep equivocation between what Schopenhaeur speaks us with reference to "a conception composed of all sorts of predicates" and what Anselm means by God. The inclusion of existence in the idea of God is problematic, but it's problematic precisely because we reject the essentialism inherent in Anselm's entire understanding of how reality works -- it's not an ad hoc hypothesis for him that the essence of pure being would exist. Rereading him in that way and claiming he's no "true scotsmanning" seems patently unfair.

Comment: The debate about Anselm's argument aside, this answer is concise, and this is, indeed, a case of begging the question. "True" Scotsmen are Scotsmen for whom the claim is true.

Comment: @kaay question-begging and true scotsman are different fallacies. Question-begging is explicitly stacking your conclusion into one or more premise.  No true scotsman is moving goal posts to meet exceptions, i.e. making something an elastic category that malleates to meet any found exception.

Comment: Whether or not you are right about about Anselm's argument, it seems tangential to the question at hand.

Comment: @virmaior  Sorry if I wasn't clear - check 3rd comment under the question.

Comment: @virmaior Would it be agreeable if I remove Anselm's name and reference Schopenhauer's reading? Older texts describe "question begging definition" as redefining the terms so as to exclude any refutation. The redefining may occur in advance, but only come to light in the course of answering objections, in practice the difference with NTS all but disappears: the Florida weather is so beautiful; but it rains and snows; ah, but that is not what I meant by "the Florida weather". Monologium overtly makes such moves, but since it is a side issue perhaps a chat is better?

Comment: I don't see how the "difference with NTS all but disappears." NTS is that someone makes a universal or general claim and then rather than accept contrary evidence tries to *later* shift the scope of the universal. I don't see how Schopenhaeur is describing that or Anslem is doing that. Instead, the accusation in both cases appears to be question-begging which is a distinct problem.

Comment: @virmaior Question begging definitions are usually revealed as such in response to exceptions. The distinction with NTS then turns on the original intention of the speaker, and unless the argument unfolds in real time it is moot. Anselm structures Monologium as response to objections. "Even a fool admits that God can be conceived" is a typical "no reasonable person" move with poisoning the well mixed in, followed by "God cannot be conceived not to exist" reveal. Did he rhetorically move the goalpost? Gaunilo, his contemporary, did name his response In Defense of Fool.

Comment: If you don't understand Anslem's argument, you can ask about it. I don't think there's any goalpost moving involved as I noted in a previous comment. Goal post moving is the key point that makes something NTS rather than a different fallacy.

Comment: @virmaior I do understand the argument, including the differences between Anselm's and more sophisticated versions. I dispute however that the distinction you are trying to draw between NTS and QBD is clear cut in all except the most blatant cases, and your claim that Anselm does not make a QBD/NTS shift between "conception of God" he has his fool admit to, and the one he uses later in the argument. What makes it particularly NTS like is that Anselm *needs* the shift for his argument to go through. Otherwise, either his premise can be denied, or Gaunilo gets his perfect island to exist too.

Answer (score 3):

All informal fallacies are superficially similar to strong arguments --they draw force from being mistaken for them.  In the case where "Scotsman" has a clearly delineated, non-mutable set of defining traits, it is not fallacious to require correspondence with those traits.  The *No True Scotsman* fallacy is when the defining criteria are altered or introduced solely as an attempt to escape a disfavored claim ("You said all Scotsmen are honest, but MacGregor is a liar."  "Well, MacGregor is no true Scotsman, then!").

What, however, about the case where two terms are proposed from the start, both "Scotsman" *and* "True Scotsman"?  It might be that, as you progress, you legitimately refine your understanding of what a "True Scotsman" needs to be.  In that case, however, you end with two terms defined differently.  It is subsequently illegitimate to take things you have established for the "True Scotsman" and apply them to the "Scotsman."